# How to restrict input to what is needed? ( eg: no numbers where letters are supposed to be inputted )

Tags: c, input

Can anyone tell me what is the best way to check input type? For example if I ask someone to enter their name, I want to make sure that they don’t enter numbers. OR the same way around when I ask for their age, I don’t want letters to be imputed. I’ve tried using switch statements, but this doesn’t seem  to be good idea.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the input in the form of a C string? Do you have a "regular expression" library available? That would be the simplest way to check. Otherwise you have to examine the string character by character and check isalpha(), isdigit() etc.

Comment: Use functions like `isdigit` and `isalpha` to test whether a character is a number or a letter.

Comment: `sscanf()` idea:  `char buf[100]; fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); int n = -1; sscanf(buf, " %*[A-Za-z ]%*[\n]%n", &n);  if (n > 0 && buf[n] == '\0') GoodName();`

Comment: Best to use `strtol()` family of functions for testing number input.

Comment: So `Thurston Howell the 3rd` is not a name?

Comment: What about C3P0 and R2D2, for that matter?

Comment: You might consider reading http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ before you write more code that manipulates names.

Answer (score 0):

`isalpha()` in C only works for characters. Build a function that iterates through a string and checks if all characters are accepted by `isalpha()`

See:

```
int string_is_name(char *s)
{
    int i;
    int valid = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (!isalpha(s[i])) {
            valid = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: 1) Better to use `!isalpha((unsigned char) s[i])` to prevent UB.  2) Better to use `size_t i;`

Comment: @chux you use size_t for your loop indices? Why is that a better approach?

Comment: @chux The only reason I can think of is because of overflow (if you had more than MAX_INT elements in your array), but would that really happen here? It is clearer to use int or unsigned int, no?

Comment: Which is clearer `int`, `unsigned`, `size_t` is a subjective question - so no definitive answer is readily possible.  But using `size_t` technically is correct for both `size_t` is the return type of `strlen()` and `size_t` is well defined for indexing arrays from the base `s`.  `int` suffers from negative indexing (not applicable here) and range as you mentioned.  "would that really happen here?": not likely unless someone writes a virus on a 64-bit machine to take advantage of the `int` range weakness.  I recommend practicing safe indexing.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I'll keep this in mind for the future.